# Restarting a Rails Server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, touch

What exactly does this command do, in regards to running a Rails server?

```
~$ sudo touch restart.txt
```

I thought it restarts the Rails server, but it happens so fast when I run it, that I can hardly believe it's really rebooting the Rails server. It's fixed my problem a bunch of times, but I would like to know why it works, and what it's doing.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using Passenger, then it's monitoring the timestamp of the `tmp/restart.txt` file to trigger restarts.

Comment: ahh, so passenger is looking at it and when it sees a newer timestamp, it knows to restart itself?

Comment: @Goldentoa11 yes.